# How can I refer to what called a function in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list

I was wondering if there is a way in C++ to know what called a function? Like the this keyword in Java or JavaScript.

For example, I have a function called insert, which inserts an item into a linked list, I want the linked-list that called those the function insert to call two other functions. How would I do that?

I have this right now, is this valid?

```
bool linked_list::insert( int i )
{
    bool inserted = false;

    if( this.is_present(i) ) /* function is_present is defined earlier checks if an int is already in the linked-list. */
    {
        inserted = true // already inside the linked-list
    }
    else
    {
        this.Put( 0, i ); /* function Put is defined earlier and puts an int in a linked-list at a given position (first param.). */
        inserted = true; // it was put it.

    }
return inserted;
}
```

Comment: Your terminology is a little incorrect. The linked list does not call `insert`; `insert` is called *on* the linked list. The function is called by some other function that uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [historical reasons](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#this), `this` is a pointer. Use `->` instead of `.`.

```
bool linked_list::insert(int i) {
    bool inserted = false;

    if(this->is_present(i)) {
        inserted = true; // fixed syntax error while I was at it.
    } else {
        this->put(0, i); // fixed inconsistent naming while I was at it.
        inserted = true;
    }
    return inserted;
}
```

Usually it is not needed to use `this->` at all; you can just do `if(is_present(i))`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` works in c++ the same as it does in Java. The only difference is that you need to use `this->` instead of `this.` `this` is a pointer than therefor you cannot use the dot operator to access it's members.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just call the other functions in `linked_list::insert(int)`? And no, it is not valid, you should put `this -> something` instead of `this.something`